# Stretch two buttons inside a WrapPanel

Tags: c#, wpf

I am switching from Windows Forms to WPF and I would like to copy the GUI over. Since just running it through a converter gives horrible code I am giving it a go myself. Though when I try to create a simple groupbox, it already is giving me troubles.

I want to create this:

[image]

But I end up with this:

[image]

This is the XAML:

```
<GroupBox Header="Search" Width="200">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox />
        <WrapPanel>
            <Button Content="Reset" />
            <Button Content="Search" />
        </WrapPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</GroupBox>
```

If I play around with `HorizontalAlignment` it doesn't do anything. I want to stretch the buttons (50% each) but I can't seem to find a way to get it done. I feel as if `WrapPanel` maybe isn't the right container here, but I can't find an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Grid` container or the `UniformGrid` container.

**Example 1** (`Grid` instead of `WrapPanel`):

```
<GroupBox Header="Search" Width="200">
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBox />
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Reset" Margin="0,5,5,0" />
      <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Search" Margin="5,5,0,0" />
    </Grid>
  </StackPanel>
</GroupBox>
```

**Example 2** (`Grid` for whole layout):

```
<GroupBox Header="Search" Width="200">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Reset" Margin="0,5,5,0" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="Search" Margin="5,5,0,0" />
  </Grid>
</GroupBox>
```

**Example 3** (`UniformGrid` instead of `WrapPanel`):

```
<GroupBox Header="Search" Width="200">
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBox />
    <UniformGrid Columns="2" Rows="1">
      <Button Content="Reset" Margin="0,5,5,0" />
      <Button Content="Search" Margin="5,5,0,0" />
    </UniformGrid>
  </StackPanel>
</GroupBox>
```

**Result layout for all examples:**

[image]

**Useful links**

- [MSDN: WPF Container Controls Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb514628.aspx)
- [MSDN: Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx)
- [MSDN: UniformGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid.aspx)
- [CodeProject: WPF Tutorial : Layout-Panels-Containers & Layout Transformation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140613/WPF-Tutorial-Layout-Panels-Containers-Layout-Trans)
- [CodeProject: WPF Layouts - A Visual Quick Start](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30904/WPF-Layouts-A-Visual-Quick-Start)
- [2,000 Things You Should Know About WPF: UniformGrid](http://wpf.2000things.com/tag/uniformgrid/)

Comment: This looks good. Too bad I have to create an entire `Grid` just for two elements, would been more elegant in a `WrapPanel` in my opinion. Thanks for the quick help!

Comment: @Gideon You could use a `UniformGrid` instead if you don't want to define columns.

Comment: @Gideon, Grid is a very useful layout container. It is totally ok to use it for two elements. I have updated the example with more flexibale layout.

Comment: Kudos for the complete answer! I used the `UniformGrid` approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<GroupBox Header="Search" Width="200" >
    <GroupBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4"></Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type FrameworkElement}}" />
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type FrameworkElement}}" />
    </GroupBox.Resources>
    <StackPanel Margin="2">
        <TextBox />
        <UniformGrid Rows="1">
            <Button Content="Reset" />
            <Button Content="Search" IsDefault="True" />
        </UniformGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</GroupBox>
```

Comment: This looks interesting, can you describe what's going on in here?

Comment: Of course. The resources part defines the specific resources that will be shared along the visual tree. If you define a style, then it's shared with all the children. It contains a base style targeting all FrameworkElement.

Comment: That is really nice actually, going to use some of this. Thanks!

Comment: There is a limitation with styles targeting FrameworkElement, and it's that they're so general that are "forbidden". However, they can be used as a base for more concrete styles. This is what I do in the other 2 styles. One targets Buttons, and the other, TextBoxes. This way, you get all the margins without repeating and centralizing, which is great for flexibility and mantainability :)

Comment: Feel free to ask! I love XAML!